# Xamarin Forms Switch Nightmare

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I can't believe I have spent a day trying to get this to work! I began developing in Xamarin.Forms last month and for the most part things have been going pretty smooth. My background is ASP.Net MVC and Windows Forms so the MVVM concept is new to me.

The issue that I am having is very frustrating and seems silly really. I imagine it could be my implementation possibly because I am not using MVVM but am performing all binding in the code behind? I have a page that has a search box and a ListView controll. Each of the items in the ListView is fairly simple... it only consists of a few labels and a switch. The ListView is bound every time someone performs a search. The problem that I am having is that every time someone performs a search it refreshes the Model everyting is bound to... this in turn triggers the Switches Toggle Event. Within the Toggle Event I have code that would update the database when the value is changed so I do not want this fired off every time the model changes. It is very frustrating as there does not appear to be a Click Event. See Xaml and the Method I am using below:

```
    public async void SearchItems()
    {
        PageLoaded = false;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSearch.Text)) { return; }
        this.LoadSearch.IsRunning = true;
        // Populate Locations For Item
        string ItemType = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.SelectItemType.SelectedItem.ToString());
        string Search = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.txtSearch.Text.ToLower());
        string url = string.Format("https://test.com/api/LocationsSearch?itemType={0}&search={1}", ItemType, Search);
        LocationsList = new List<Locations>();
        var json = await func.GetIBApi(url);
        LocationsList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locations>>(json);
        this.ItemsList.ItemsSource = LocationsList;
        this.LoadSearch.IsRunning = false;
        PageLoaded = true;
    }
```

Toggle Event:

```
        private async void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (PageLoaded)
                {
                    bool isPrimary = e.Value;
                    ViewCell cell = (sender as Switch).Parent.Parent.Parent as ViewCell;
                    var location = cell.BindingContext as Locations;

                    string display = "";
                    if (isPrimary)
                    {
                        display = "Are you sure you want to make this the 'Primary Location'?";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        display = "Are you sure you want to unset this as the 'Primary Location'? Note: Make sure you set another location as the 'Primary' on this PartNumber!";
                    }

                    var result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Primary Change Confirmation", display, "Yes", "No");
                    if (result)
                    {
                        string url = string.Format("https://test.com/api/LocationsSearch?partNumber={0}&location={1}&isPrimary={2}", location.ID, location.Location, isPrimary);
                        var json = await func.PostIBApi(url);
                        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {

            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IBMobile.Views.LocationsPage"
             xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
             Visual="Material">
    <ContentPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static local2:IconFont.MapMarkerAlt}" />
    </ContentPage.IconImageSource>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="25">
            <Picker  x:Name="SelectItemType" SelectedIndexChanged="SelectItemType_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <SearchBar x:Name="txtSearch" SearchButtonPressed="TxtSearch_SearchButtonPressed"  Placeholder="Search..." FontSize="Title"></SearchBar>
            <ActivityIndicator Color="#007D5D" IsRunning="false" x:Name="LoadSearch"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsList" ItemTapped="ItemsList_ItemTapped"  HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="White">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label TextColor="#007D5D" Text="{Binding ViewID}" FontSize="Title" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                                    <Label TextColor="#007D5D" Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="Title" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="Primary" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsPrimary}" x:Name="Toggle1" ThumbColor="#007D5D" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Toggled="Switch_Toggled"/>
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding Description}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding Message}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Some code is missing, where is IsPrimary set?

Comment: @NickKovalsky See modified, thanks.

Comment: The Toggle Event still triggered during the searching action after you added PageLoaded? It shouldn't.

Comment: Can you please provide us a sample which can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (PageLoaded)
                    {
                        //entered handler
                        bool isPrimary = e.Value; //we are invoking the handler again from inside itsself
                                                  // all the mess comes from this
```

Use another lock:

```
 if (PageLoaded && !_internal)
                        {
                            //entered handler
                            _internal=true;
                            bool isPrimary = e.Value;
                            _internal=false;
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried something similar which I know wasn't plainly obvious as I was missing the Toggle Event. In my code the property flag is called PageLoaded which I am setting at the start and finish of the Search method. Any ideas?

Comment: The idea is your mess comes when IsPrimary that is set while PageLoaded=true; you are basically calling the handler twice, from inside itsself

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same results. The fact is it is hitting the Event every time I perform a search.

Comment: Looking at your code, what you are saying is it executes the code inside if (PageLoaded) when PageLoaded==false, am i right?